# How to look for files not having the word TEST using ack

Tags: regex, ack

I love ack.

I need to search for 'foo' in all the files except the test files.

ack has option -G to specify regex. However I am not sure how do I write regex for the condition that look for all files but ignore files with word 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*test.*).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with ack 2.0, you need to specify a file type and then filter based on it. In this case, you want to skip files with the word test in them:

```
ack --type-set testfiles:match:'test' --type=notestfiles pattern
```

Note: I'm using the negative of the file type `testifies`, so I've appended `no` to filetype, as per the documentation:

> --type=noX                    Exclude X files.
>                                   See "ack --help-types" for supported filetypes.